# Ignore specific proprety of object in list

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapstruct

I have these objects:

Class of domain

```
public class Partecipation implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "partecipation")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    private Set<DesignatedCompany> designatedCompanies = new HashSet<>();
...
}
```

My DTO

```
public class PartecipationDTO implements Serializable { 
    private Long id;
...
    private Set<DesignatedCompanyDTO> designatedCompanies = new HashSet<>();
...
}
```

Connected DTO

```
public class DesignatedCompanyDTO implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
...
    private PartecipationDTO partecipation;
...
}
```

And I have this mapper:

```
public interface PartecipationMapper extends EntityMapper<PartecipationDTO, Partecipation> {
...
    PartecipationDTO toDto(Partecipation partecipation);
}
```

Correctly the code goes in error, because it enters a cyclical condition and in the details here:

```
public class PartecipationMapperImpl implements PartecipationMapper {
...
    protected DesignatedCompanyDTO designatedCompanyToDesignatedCompanyDTO(DesignatedCompany designatedCompany) {
        if ( designatedCompany == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        DesignatedCompanyDTO designatedCompanyDTO = new DesignatedCompanyDTO();

        designatedCompanyDTO.setId( designatedCompany.getId() );
        designatedCompanyDTO.setCompanyEopooCode( designatedCompany.getCompanyEopooCode() );
        designatedCompanyDTO.setNote( designatedCompany.getNote() );
        designatedCompanyDTO.setPartecipation( toDto( designatedCompany.getPartecipation() ) ); // <--- this line cause the error

        return designatedCompanyDTO;
    }
...
}
```

Is it possible to set in the mapper an exclusion for the property of child object in lists? For example, like this:

```
@Mapping(target = "designatedCompanies[].partecipation", ignore = true)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have solved the problem, tks to [filiphr](https://github.com/filiphr) (https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/933#issuecomment-265952166)

working in the Mappers of the 2 DTO, here the code:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {DesignatedCompanyMapper.class})
public interface PartecipationMapper extends EntityMapper<PartecipationDTO, Partecipation> {
...
    @Mapping(target = "designatedCompanies", qualifiedByName="NoPartecipation")
    PartecipationDTO toDto(Partecipation partecipation);
...
}
```

And the Mapper of Iterable Object

```
public interface DesignatedCompanyMapper extends EntityMapper<DesignatedCompanyDTO, DesignatedCompany> {
    @Mapping(source = "partecipation.id", target = "partecipationId")
    DesignatedCompanyDTO toDto(DesignatedCompany designatedCompany);
...
    @Named("NoPartecipation")
    @Mapping(source = "partecipation.id", target = "partecipationId")
    @Mapping(target = "partecipation", ignore = true)
    DesignatedCompanyDTO toDtoNoPartecipation(DesignatedCompany designatedCompany);
}
```